# How to iterate over stdin in Dart efficiently?

Tags: dart

I wrote my first Dart commandline utility for Linux today. It is supposed to process a file piped to it through stdin. Ultimately each line is then processed. But I feel like I used a very inefficient way to read the file, so I hope to get some hints. Here is a minimum example of the code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
    var line = stdin.readLineSync();
    for (;line != null; line = stdin.readLineSync() ) {
        //do stuff with line or simply
        stdout.writeln(line);
    }
}
```

This is then used like this:

```
zcat some_data.csv.gz | ./my_dart_tool.exe > output_file.csv
```

Is that a reasonable way to iterate over stdin in Dart or is it supposed to be done differently?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you think it's so inefficient? You could read it char by char, rather than by line, but I think in a CSV processing utility - what this seems to be - a line by line approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: Why do you wanna print the file into the console and then read stdin ? Wouldn't it be easier to unzip the archive, open the csv file and then read it line by line ?

Comment: @ Gerard: Because without any processing of the piped lines (or file) it already takes minutes to iterate over the input. The actual computation of the same file, only takes 10 to 25 sec in Python, Java, JS or GO. 
@ Maxouille: Like I wrote it's a minimum example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bad performance of `stdin.readLineSync` is a know issue and there are GitHub issue on the Dart SDK issue tracker here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45255

The problem is that Dart does not want to read more data than necessary so it try to read a byte one at a time until it finds a newline. This is not very efficient since this adds a lot of communication between the native layer and Dart code.

Until this is fixed, a workaround is to do something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  await for (final line in stdin.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(const LineSplitter())) {
    //do stuff with line or simply
    print(line);
  }
}
```

Here we are instead reading a bunch of bytes inside a buffer then transform it with `utf8.decode` which then sends it into `LineSplitter` which returns lines. This is more efficient since we can lower the amount of times we are making a read to `stdin` since we are reading a lot more data each time we ask for it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This already brings the time for just looping over the file from approx. 20 min down to only 15 sec!

Comment: @StackSeeker Yes, it is surprising how bad the overhead really is... :D

Comment: I can confirm that this also resolves performance issues when reading small lines (a big amount of them). We are in 2023 and it seems like the `stdin.readLineSync` performance issue still exists.